# Can I convert an Android 1.6 project to 2.0?

Tags: android

I have an Android 1.6 project. Can I directly convert it to 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume "Convert" means making build for another version.

In Project Explorer, right click on Project name, select Properties -> Android , In "Project Build Target" section, select the SDK version number as you have download onto your machine.